# Resizable split DIVs Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, sass

Hi fellow Developers/Programmers!

I just started Developing Web App (Vue.js) for my company for around 1-2 months.
Therefore, my knowledge and experience in HTML, CSS and Javascript is kinda shallow.

I've created a custom resizable split DIVs and it working just fine as what I wanted.
However, I would like to know if my  code is a **good code** or a **bad code**.
Below is a snippet of my code. Live demo: https://codepen.io/aziziaziz/pen/yLBeRxQ

```js
var dividerRef = '';
var currentDivider = null;

var leftDivider = null;
var rightDivider = null;
var leftRightDivider = null;

var topLeft = null;
var topRight = null;
var bottomLeft = null;
var bottomRight = null;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: 
  {
  dividerDragStart: function(e) {
   e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image, 0, 0);
  },
    dividerDrag: function(e) {
   if (dividerRef == 'lrDivider') {
    currentDivider.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';

    leftDivider.style.width = (e.clientX + 2) + 'px';

    rightDivider.style.left = (e.clientX) + 'px';
    rightDivider.style.width = (window.innerWidth - e.clientX + 2) + 'px';

    topLeft.style.width = e.clientX + 'px';
    bottomLeft.style.width = e.clientX + 'px';

    topRight.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    topRight.style.width = (window.innerWidth - e.clientX + 2) + 'px';
    bottomRight.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    bottomRight.style.width = (window.innerWidth - e.clientX + 2) + 'px';
   } else if (dividerRef == 'rtbDivider') {
    currentDivider.style.top = (e.clientY) + 'px';

    topRight.style.height = (e.clientY) + 'px'

    bottomRight.style.height = (window.innerHeight - e.clientY) + 'px';
    bottomRight.style.top = (e.clientY) + 'px';
   } else if (dividerRef == 'ltbDivider') {
    currentDivider.style.top = (e.clientY) + 'px';

    topLeft.style.height = (e.clientY) + 'px'

    bottomLeft.style.height = (window.innerHeight - e.clientY) + 'px';
    bottomLeft.style.top = (e.clientY) + 'px';
   }
  },
  dividerMouseDown: function(name) {
   dividerRef = name;
   currentDivider = this.$refs[dividerRef];
  },
  dividerDragEnd: function(e) {
   if (dividerRef == 'lrDivider') {
    currentDivider.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    leftDivider.style.width = (e.clientX + 2) + 'px';

    rightDivider.style.left = (e.clientX) + 'px';
    rightDivider.style.width = (window.innerWidth - e.clientX + 2) + 'px';

    topLeft.style.width = e.clientX + 'px';
    bottomLeft.style.width = e.clientX + 'px';

    topRight.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    topRight.style.width = (window.innerWidth - e.clientX + 2) + 'px';
    bottomRight.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    bottomRight.style.width = (window.innerWidth - e.clientX + 2) + 'px';
   } else if (dividerRef == 'rtbDivider') {
    currentDivider.style.top = (e.clientY) + 'px';

    topRight.style.height = (e.clientY) + 'px'

    bottomRight.style.height = (window.innerHeight - e.clientY) + 'px';
    bottomRight.style.top = (e.clientY) + 'px';
   } else if (dividerRef == 'ltbDivider') {
    currentDivider.style.top = (e.clientY) + 'px';

    topLeft.style.height = (e.clientY) + 'px'

    bottomLeft.style.height = (window.innerHeight - e.clientY) + 'px';
    bottomLeft.style.top = (e.clientY) + 'px';
   }

   dividerRef = '';
   currentDivider = null;
  }
  },
  mounted() {
    topLeft = this.$refs.topLeft;
    topRight = this.$refs.topRight;
    bottomLeft = this.$refs.bottomLeft;
    bottomRight = this.$refs.bottomRight;

    var heightHalf = (window.innerHeight - 80) / 2;
  var widthHalf = window.innerWidth / 2;
  
  leftDivider = this.$refs.ltbDivider;
  rightDivider = this.$refs.rtbDivider;
  leftRightDivider = this.$refs.lrDivider;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div class="top-left" ref="topLeft">
      <div class="text-area">
        <h3>Resize me using the black bars</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-right" ref="topRight">
      <div class="text-area">
        <h3>Resize me using the black bars</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-left" ref="bottomLeft">
      <div class="text-area">
        <h3>Resize me using the black bars</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-right" ref="bottomRight">
      <div class="text-area">
        <h3>Resize me using the black bars</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="left-right divider" ref="lrDivider" @mousedown="dividerMouseDown('lrDivider')" draggable="true"
        @drag="dividerDrag" @dragend="dividerDragEnd" @dragstart="dividerDragStart"></div>
    <div class="right-top-bottom divider" ref="rtbDivider" @mousedown="dividerMouseDown('rtbDivider')" draggable="true"
        @drag="dividerDrag" @dragend="dividerDragEnd" @dragstart="dividerDragStart"></div>
    <div class="left-top-bottom divider" ref="ltbDivider" @mousedown="dividerMouseDown('ltbDivider')" draggable="true"
        @drag="dividerDrag" @dragend="dividerDragEnd" @dragstart="dividerDragStart"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So if any Web Developer master would like to give feedback, comments or opinions on my code, would be much appreciated.

I'm sorry if this is not really a question, but I really want to get feedbacks on my code and I don't know where else to refer to besides here. Sorry guys.

Thank you so much for your time.
Appreciate it.

Comment: You should use the codereview Stack exchange https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @gugateider Thank you so much for that information. Didn't know about that. Will definitely post one there. Thanks!